# Python Export table from postgres and import to another postgres using

Tags: python, database, postgresql

I have 2 postgres databases with same schema but in 2 different schemas. I am writing a python script with a goal to export data partially from one of the tables and import the result to the same table but in a different database (like `select from A where f=123`). The schema is large (it has many columns of different types, some are allowed to be null, some aren't. There are date types and string fields which can contain sentences, pseudo-queries and file names) and there can be thousands of rows in a table.

I took approach of exporting the data from table to a csv file, then importing the data from a csv file to a second database table.

I use `psycopg2` lib for working with Postgres in Python along with a `csv` lib to read and write csv files.

I implemented the first version. The problem was that: Some columns in a row are empty, when I read the table data in python the empty fields have `None` value when the field is allowed to be `null` and where the field is not allowed to be `null` the value is `""` empty string and when exported to csv all the values which are `None` and `""` are inserted as empty strings in a csv file. As an example the row would look like this `1234,,,,,1,,`. And when I try to import the file to a postgres table all empty values in a csv are converted to `null` and are tried to insert this way, but it failed because fields which can't be `null` don't accept this value. Below you can see my code and after that code I pasted the improvement i did to avoid this problem.

```
import psycopg2
import csv

def export_table(filename, tablename):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(....)

    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute(f'SELECT * FROM {tablename} where f=123')

    rows = cur.fetchall()

    with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        for row in rows:
            writer.writerow(row)

    cur.close()
    conn.close()


def import_table(filename, tablename):

    conn = psycopg2.connect(..second db data)

    cur = conn.cursor()
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        cur.copy_expert(
            f"COPY {tablename} FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT CSV)",
            csvfile
        )

    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

I tried to add `csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL`, `csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` - they did not help me.

Because I was not able to import the data with this code, I tried to try one more thing.

I added a manual function for quoting:

```
def quote_field(field):
    if isinstance(field, str):
        if field == '':
            return '""'
        elif any(c in field for c in (',', '"', '\n')):
            return '"' + field.replace('"', '""') + '"'

    return field
```

And updated the import part this way:

```
with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar='', escapechar='\\')
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow([quote_field(field) for field in row])
```

I tried running the code, it pasting null values to a csv as `""` and `None` values are placed in a csv as just empty fields. So a row in a csv would look like this `1234,,,"","",,,,,"",,,,,` and for some of the cases this would successfully work, the data was imported correctly. But sometimes for some reason the csv that is generated is not imported at all or just partially. To check it I tried to use DataGrip to import data from a csv file manually, for some data it was also importing it just partially (like 20 rows out of 1000) and for some data it was not importing at all. I checked the csv's for validity, they were valid.
I think there's a bug in an import part but i don't know where it is and why it is behaving this way. Need help with this.

Comment: Why not just use [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) and import directly from one database to the other?

Comment: Option 2: Use `psycopg2` [COPY](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from) functions to do the export as well.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks for the reply. As I understood `postgres_fdw` is an extension that should be installed in postgres, but i don't understand how can I partially copy the data from the table in one server to the table in another server. And also this is the part of an automation job, so i need to have a runnable script. 
I use copy_expert which i think uses copy_to implicitly

Comment: 1) `postgres_fdw`. `Insert into local_tbl select * from remote_tbl where <some_filters>` 2) `copy_expert` can be either from to.  You can use it to do `COPY (SELECT * FROM tablename where f=123) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER`. FYI, **do not** use `f` strings to build a query. The safe way is to use the [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create tables:

```
create table csv_null(id integer not null, fld1 varchar);
insert into csv_null values (1, 'test'), (2, ''), (3, null), (4, 'cat');
create table csv_null_2 as select * from csv_null limit 0;
 \pset null
Null display is "NULL".
select * from csv_null;
 id | fld1 
----+------
  1 | test
  2 | 
  3 | NULL
  4 | cat
```

Python code:

```
import io
import psycopg2
con = psycopg2.connect(dbname="test", host='localhost', user='postgres', port=5432)
buffer = io.StringIO()
cur = con.cursor()
cur.copy_expert('copy (select * from csv_null ) TO  STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER', buffer)

buffer.seek(0)
cur.copy_expert('copy csv_null_2 from  STDIN WITH CSV HEADER', buffer)
con.commit()

cur.execute("select * from csv_null_2")
cur.fetchall()
[(1, 'test'), (2, ''), (3, None), (4, 'cat')]
```

In psql:

```
select * from csv_null_2 ;
 id | fld1 
----+------
  1 | test
  2 | 
  3 | NULL
  4 | cat
```

The `cur.copy_expert('copy (select * from csv_null ) TO  STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER', buffer)` is going to produce output that `cur.copy_expert('copy csv_null_2 from  STDIN WITH CSV HEADER', buffer)` is going to consume correctly. You are not jumping from one context Python `csv` to Postgres `COPY`.

**UPDATE**

Table altered to have `NOT NULL` column:

```
alter table csv_null add column fld2 varchar not null default '';
update csv_null set fld2 = 'not null' where id in (1,4);
alter table csv_null_2 add column fld2 varchar not null default '';
truncate csv_null_2;
```

Python code:

```
buffer = io.StringIO()
cur.copy_expert('copy (select * from csv_null ) TO  STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER', buffer)
buffer.seek(0)
cur.copy_expert('copy csv_null_2 from  STDIN WITH CSV HEADER', buffer)
con.commit()

cur.execute("select * from csv_null_2")
cur.fetchall()
[(2, '', ''), (3, None, ''), (1, 'test', 'not null'), (4, 'cat', 'not null')]
```

In `psql`:

```
select * from csv_null_2 ;
 id | fld1 |   fld2   
----+------+----------
  2 |      | 
  3 | NULL | 
  1 | test | not null
  4 | cat  | not null
```

Comment: Thanks for a reply! Here the field fld1 basically accepts all values including `null`. But in my case the failing fields were the ones that hold varchar values, but do not accept `null`, so they basically have `not null` restrictions. Will your code work if you add a third column which is a `varchar not null`?

Comment: Also you are storing the exported data in a buffer which is in-memory, which i believe imposes a risk of overflow in case there's too many rows. (also tables in my db have around 90 columns, so in my case the overflow risk is significantly higher).

Comment: Per [copy_expert](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert):  *copy_expert(sql, file, size=8192) ...file – a file-like object to read or write (according to sql).*, so you could write it out to on disk file and then use that file to `cur.copy_expert('copy <table> from ...')`..

Comment: See **UPDATE** for `NOT NULL` case.

Comment: I've seen your update, this solution solves my issue.

Comment: Though the reason the data from csv was inserted partially was the issues with a table itself (it did not allow insert for some cases). I've done some testing, my solution and your work the same way, but your is more laconic takes care of deleting the temporary file. Thanks for the solution! Just a question i wanted to ask, this buffer file that it uses, does it have any space usage limits?

Comment: AFAIK, amount of memory. All the details can be found here [io](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#module-io) module.